# How to get the value of a specific cookie in CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

How to get the value of a specific cookie in CefSharp?

Source:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;

namespace selfbot_gui
{
    public partial class CultureLandWeb : Form
    {
        private ChromiumWebBrowser _chrome = null;
        public CultureLandWeb()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            InitializeCefSharp();
        }
        private void InitializeCefSharp()
        {
     
            _chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://google.com/");
       
            _chrome.BrowserSettings.AcceptLanguageList = "ko-KR";
            
            this.Controls.Add(_chrome);
 
            _chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
    }
}
```

For example, how would I code to get a specific cookie value ["NID"] from https://google.com?
I want to get the cookie value ["NID"] and store it in a variable.

Comment: Start by reading https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#retrieve-cookies You can get cookies for a specific domain, then search through the array to find the one you are after.